# How can I get the spreadsheet id using a clock trigger?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have built a workflow system in a Spreadsheet with email notifications as one of the features. The function for the email reminders is triggered by a clock trigger once a day.

Today it looks like this:

```
function sendMailReminder(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
```

As long as I only have one spreadsheet, I can use the ID without problem, but now I'd like to share this spreadsheet with other workgroups. And I would like to do this without having to access the code and change the ID every time.

So - how can I access the spreadsheet ID related to the clock trigger? Is it possible?

Comment: what is your criteria for target spreadsheets. Are they following a particular name pattern, or are they in an specific folder. Based on your query/search criteria, you can loop through spreadsheets and do required operations. It will be great if you elaborate your question a little.

Comment: Thanks, Waqar!

I would like to be able to share the spreadsheet in an youth organization where people will use it in different workgroups. It would be great if this email reminder functionality could work in every copy of the spreadsheet without having to change the ID in code.

There will be no pattern except that they all have the same three sheets...

Is there no way to connect the script to the document which it is attached to?

Comment: SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId() will certainly work to get the id of the container spreadsheet. Sice you are using MailApp/GmailApp, you will have to run the script at least once ,manually so that the script get authorized to send emails. I am not sure what type of workflow you are developing but I'll suggest you to manage all this centrally. make copies of spreadsheet without codes and make a Master Spreadsheet which will have access to all copies of spreadsheets and do the notification thing on their behalf.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a script embedded in the spreadsheet, get the id of the active spreadsheet and send it via email.

```
var spreadsheet_id = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
```